# Java: NoSuchMethodError with PDPageContentStream

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to use `PDFBox` in Java but get a `NoSuchMethodError` when trying to create a `PDPageContentStream` object.
The error I get at execution is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.hasContents()Z
```

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like you have different versions of PDFBox libraries in you class path, and the `PDPageContentStream` code in one such library is expected to be loaded givel the `PDPage` definition from another library.

Answer (score 9):

The problem has been solved. I had added two different versions of pdfbox to my project. When I removed the older version, the NoSuchMethodError disappeared.